# Converting points from British National Grid/OSGB to lat-long in client side

Tags: coordinate-system, javascript, coordinates, software-recommendations, d3

I'm working on a front-end application that needs points in pixels. The data array object from API calls returns GIS values as `British National Grid/OSGB 1936 CRS (coordinate reference system) of 27700` points and these points need to be mapped to pixels for further rendering. I looked at the d3.js `d3-geo` library for mapping lat/long values to pixels. For that, I need to convert from `British National Grid/OSGB` to lat/long.

Is there any package/library to do this?

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the comment suggestion of using proj4js, you could also consider https://github.com/OrdnanceSurvey/os-transform which wraps the proj4js implementation to make it easier for this specific use case.